# How to integrate the pagination in the code example using the query

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

How to get items per page working and the current and next page functionality working for this code and also how to get the relevant data in chunks from the backend using the sequelize?

```
// controller
const getdailyExpense = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const response = await dailyExpense.findAll({
      where: { UserId: req.authUser.id },
    });
    res.json(response);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("error in getdailyexpense controller");
  }
};

// FrontEnd
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", async () => {
  const token = localStorage.getItem("token");
  const decodeToken = parseJwt(token);
  // console.log(decodeToken);
  const response = await axios.get("http://localhost:3000/dailyExpense", {
    headers: { Authorization: token },
  });
  // I want to add pagination for this one
  response.data.forEach((element) => {
    onScreenFunction(element);
  });
  const ispremiumuser = decodeToken.ispremiumuser;
  // console.log({ decodeToken, ispremiumuser });
  if (ispremiumuser) {
    showPremiumuserMessage();
    showLeaderboard();
    showDownloadBtn();
    showPeriodicBtn();
  }
});
```

I tried got the result from the stackoverflow: someone closed my previous question without giving what was so unclear that is why posting again :(

Answer (score 0):

```
// controller
const getdailyExpense = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    let page = Number(req.query.page) || 1;
    let limit = parseInt(req.query.limit) || 10;
    let offset = (page - 1) * limit;

    const response = await dailyExpense.findAll({
      where: { UserId: req.authUser.id },
      limit: limit,
      offset: offset
    });
    res.json(response);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("error in getdailyexpense controller");
  }
};
```

- Define the variable called page and assign a value to the page query parameter from the request object `req.query.page`, the default is page 1.
- Define the variable called limit to set the no of records on the page, taken the default as 10 items.
- The offset is used to determine the starting point of the records to be fetched from the database.
- The `limit` and `offset` options are also specified in `findAll()` method to control the number of records to be fetched.

Comment: And how would I handle the data in the frontend as the data I am getting in the chunks now?